# Expand matched strings in sed

Tags: bash, sed

Is it possible to expand the matched string in a sed command? I want to substitute variable names in a file with their values, this is my script at the moment:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Running the build script..."
VAR1="2005648"
VAR2="7445aa"
SERVER_NAME=$(hostname)
TIMESTAMP=$(date +%m-%d-%Y)
sed -i "s/{[A-Z_][A-Z_]*}/$&/g" my_file.txt  #variable names in the file are written between { }
```

and this is a snapshot of my_file.txt:

```
Building finished at {TIMESTAMP}
{VAR1}:{VAR2}
On: {SERVER_NAME}
current working directory: {PWD}
```

But it doesn't work. Instead of substituting the variable name with it's value, It inserts a dollar sign right before the curly bracket.
How do I resolve this?

Comment: Your shebang is missing a `#`

Comment: Care to explain?

Comment: Try  https://shellcheck.net  to verify your script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `envsubst` to substitute environment variables, otherwise you would need a bunch of `sed` commands to replace everything.

Change your template file to:

```
Building finished at ${TIMESTAMP}
${VAR1}:${VAR2}
On: ${SERVER_NAME}
current working directory: ${PWD}
```

And the script to:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Running the build script..."
export VAR1="2005648"
export VAR2="7445aa"
export SERVER_NAME=$(hostname)
export TIMESTAMP=$(date +%m-%d-%Y)

# only replace the defined variables
envsubst '$VAR1 $VAR2 $SERVER_NAME $TIMESTAMP' < my_file.txt > newfile

# replace all environment variables ($USER, $HOME, $HOSTNAME, etc.)
#envsubst < my_file.txt > newfile.txt > newfile
```

The script replaces environment variables `$VAR1`, `$VAR2`, `$SERVER_NAME` and `$TIMESTAMP` in `my_file.txt` and saves the output to `newfile`.
You can see that `${PWD}` doesn't get replaced, because I forgot to add it to the list.

In the second commented example all environment variables are replaced and non-existing variables are replaced by an empty string.

You can use the `$VARNAME` or `${VARNAME}` syntax in the template.

Comment: +1 but IMO it could be done by `eval` without of enumerating variables (for relatively small files of course)

Answer (score 2):

I'd actually do it in a single pass this way using an awk that supports `ENVIRON[]`, e.g. any POSIX awk:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/bin/env bash

echo "Running the build script..."

VAR1=2005648 \
VAR2=7445aa \
SERVER_NAME=$(hostname) \
TIMESTAMP=$(date +%m-%d-%Y) \
awk '
{
    while ( match($0,/{[[:alnum:]_]+}/) ) {
        printf "%s", substr($0,1,RSTART-1) ENVIRON[substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)]
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    print
}
' file

$ ./tst.sh
Running the build script...
Building finished at 04-14-2020
2005648:7445aa
On: MyLogin
current working directory: /home/MyLogin
```

but if you really want to do multiple passes calling sed inside a shell loop then `${!variable}` is your friend, here's a start:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/bin/env bash

VAR1='2005648'
VAR2='7445aa'
SERVER_NAME='foo'

for var in VAR1 VAR2 SERVER_NAME; do
    echo "var, $var, ${!var}"
done

$ ./tst.sh
var, VAR1, 2005648
var, VAR2, 7445aa
var, SERVER_NAME, foo
```

.

```
$ VAR1='stuff'
$ var='VAR1'; echo 'foo {VAR1} bar' | sed "s/{$var}/${!var}/"
foo stuff bar
```

The awk script is robust but YMMV using sed depending on the contents of the variables, e.g. it'd fail if they contain `&` or `/` or `\1` or .... ENVIRON[] only has access to shell variables set on the awk command line or exported, hence the escape at the end of each line that sets a shell variable so it's part of the awk command line.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Running the build script..."
VAR1="2005648"
VAR2="7445aa"
SERVER_NAME=$(hostname)
TIMESTAMP=$(date +%m-%d-%Y)

sed "s|{TIMESTAMP}|$TIMESTAMP|;s|{VAR1}|$VAR1|;s|{VAR2}|$VAR2|;s|{SERVER_NAME}|$SERVER_NAME|;s|{PWD}|$PWD|" file.txt
```

Just add `{}` in the variables e.g. `{$TIMESTAMP}` and so on, if you really need it.

That should work unless there is something more that is not included in the question above.